# Does MFC CRichEditCtrl has a display level?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

i'm currently working on a legacy project in MFC.

I encounter an issue where i create a bunch of CRichEditCtrl objs in the view, many of them are overlapping each other. When i select them, the visual is totally messed up.

Is it possible to click on a particular control and bring it to the "foreground". so i can edit on that particular control?

Other question is that is there a way to distinguish those controls dynamically?

I know when i create them, the last parementer is their ID. But when i click on those, i want command handler in parent dialog or view knows which one i'm about to edit.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear and somewhat broad. The controls should not overlap in first place. Or if they overlap for whatever reason, you should disable the "non foreground" controls by calling the `EnableWindow` method.

Comment: To correctly display overlapping child controls, you need to set the `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` style on each of the child controls. This ensures correct drawing in respect to the Z-order by applying clipping to the child controls. To bring a child window to the foreground, pass `HWND_TOP` for the `hWndInsertAfter` parameter of `SetWindowPos()`.